# Suspend Resume Threads: Java

Tags: java, multithreading, resume, suspend, thread-synchronization

When I run this code, it displays the following output:

`One  : 15
Two  : 15
One  : 14
Two  : 14
Two  : 13
One  : 13
Two  : 12
One  : 12
One  : 11
Two  : 11
Thread 1 suspended
Two  : 10
Two  : 9
Two  : 8
Two  : 7
Two  : 6
Thread 1 resumed
Thread 2 suspended
Thread 2 resumed`

The output doesn't continue till the end that is 
One:1 
Two:1
Is the **myresume** method of NewThread1 class not executed? What is the reason behind this?

Following is the code of NewThread1:

```
class NewThread1 implements Runnable{
String name;
Thread t;
boolean suspendFlag;

NewThread1(String threadname){
    name = threadname;
    t = new Thread(this, name);
    suspendFlag = false;
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run(){
    try{ 
         for(int i=15; i>0; i--){
             System.out.println(name+ " : " +i);
             Thread.sleep(200);
                synchronized(this){
                    while(suspendFlag){
                        wait();
                    }
                }
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("New thread1 Interrupted");
    }
}
synchronized void myresume(){
    suspendFlag = false;
}
void mysuspend(){
    suspendFlag = true;
}
}
```

Following is the code of NewThread1:(main() method is defined here)

```
public class Suspend_ResumeThreads {
public static void main(String args[]){
    NewThread1 ob1 = new NewThread1("One ");
    NewThread1 ob2 = new NewThread1("Two ");

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ob1.mysuspend();
        System.out.println("Thread 1 suspended");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ob1.myresume();
        System.out.println("Thread 1 resumed");

        ob2.mysuspend();
        System.out.println("Thread 2 suspended");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ob2.myresume();
        System.out.println("Thread 2 resumed");

    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("Main Interrupted");
    }

    try{
        ob1.t.join();
        ob2.t.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("Main interrupeted in join()");
    }
System.out.println("Main exiting..");    
}
}
```

Comment: You must call `.notify()` on the same object to wake up a thread stuck in a `.wait()` to that object.

Comment: When you use notify/wait this should always be associated with a state change. Notify() can occur when nothing is waiting and this will be lost, and wait() can wake spuriously.

Comment: Also mark `suspendFlag` as volatile. Or change it in `synchronized` section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `notifyAll` to interrupt a `wait()`: put

```
this.notifyAll();
```

into your `myresume()` function. But always be prepared for this notification to get lost; in particular when no thread is currently waiting then it will still succeed.

Make sure you `synchronize`/`wait`/`notify` on the *same* object. A common error is to synchronize on `this` and not realize that in the context of an anonymous inner class, `this` could be something different. And even worse, it can change when refactoring the code! A best practice is to have an `Object lock = new Object();` somewhere and always `synchronize(lock) ... lock.wait(); ... lock.notifyAll();` to avoid such programming (and refactoring) errors.

Unless you make `suspendFlag` `volatile`, there is also a chance that different threads see different values of this field (if it is not `volatile`, threads may keep a local copy in the CPU cache). Thus, it may also be good to make `mysuspend` synchronized, too.

In some cases you may need to switch to a more advanced synchronization, such as 
[java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) and [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).